# How to match the first occurrence of a string with regex?

Tags: c#, regex

I have got a string:

`@reseller-slogan:"/Slogan.png";\r\n@reseller-slogan:"/Slogan.png";\r\n@reseller-slogan:"/Slogan.png";\r\n@reseller-slogan:"/Slogan.png";\r\n`

How do I match and return only the first occurrence of `@reseller-slogan:"/Slogan.png"` in C#?

Comment: What parts of the string you're trying to match are variable?

Comment: have you done any research on how to use RegEx and some of the Supported methods [RegEx Match Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twcw2f1c%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) Google is a free tool.. try using it sometime

Comment: "how do i match and return only the first occurence of @reseller-slogan:"/Slogan.png" in C#"

Do you mean you want the index of it? You want to replace it? Or...?

Comment: Why do you have to use RegEx? string.IndexOf() will return the first instance of a substring.

Comment: `var myString = Regex.Match(input, pattern).Value`

Comment: I was asking about the pattern to match first occurence of "@reseller-slogan:"/Slogan.png"" string. I did research and usually find the answer bun not with this one. what i want to do is to find first match and replace it with some other string

Answer (score 0):

If you want to solve your task with RegEx you could use this one:

```
string sourcestring = "your slogan input string";
Regex re = new Regex(@"\@reseller\-slogan:\""\/Slogan\.png\""");
Match m = re.Match(sourcestring);
```

Another solution could be to use string functions like these:

```
string sourcestring = "your slogan input string";
string pattern = "@reseller-slogan:\"/Slogan.png\"";
string patternReplacement = "@reseller-slogan:\"/MyNewSlogan.png\"";

int strIndex = sourcestring.indexOf(pattern);
string resultStr = sourcestring.Remove(strIndex, pattern.Length)
                               .Insert(strIndex, patternReplacement);
```